# OpenMP threads, how to use omp atomic clauses correctly?

Tags: c, multithreading, ubuntu, parallel-processing, openmp

I'm trying to parallel a program that reads repetitively strings in pairs from a file. I want to use the omp atomic so as to make sure that in every loop the pair will be read correctly. I'm gonna use it like this in my code :

```
#pragma omp atomic 
{
if(a = getmystring(fp)) fprintf(fpw, "A: %s\n", a);
if(b = getmystring(fp)) fprintf(fpw, "B: %s\n", b);
}
```

My problem is that I don't know what is the difference between the clases (read,write, update, capture) so as to use the correct one.
getmystring(fp) is the function that reads one string at a time from the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you've chosen the wrong OpenMP construct.  The objective seems to be to allow only one thread to execute in your block at a time.  That means the block is intended to be a *critical region*, and the directive to use for declaring it one is `omp critical`:

```
#pragma omp critical 
{
    if(a = getmystring(fp)) fprintf(fpw, "A: %s\n", a);
    if(b = getmystring(fp)) fprintf(fpw, "B: %s\n", b);
}
```

Comment: There are key differences between the constructs.  The `critical` construct is mutually exclusive in the sense that all thread compete for the same lock (or different locks if a name is added to the construct).  An `atomic` construct only supports certain expressions and statements, and also is effective on a particular memory location.  That means, an `atomic` region for a[i] will likely run concurrently with another `atomic` on a[j] if i != j.